# How do I use share() operator properly?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, reactivex

I have stream that is triggered by `next()` method of Rx `BehaviorSubject`. How do I share the `pipedData$` stream between subscribers?

I tried to use `share` operator here to avoid heavy recalculations inside the `map` operator but no luck - every subscriber produces recalculations.

[here's stackblitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-share-with-behavior-subject?devtoolsheight=100)

Also is it possible to get number of subscribers from the source?

```
import { interval, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take, map, tap, share, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

const data$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

interval(1000).pipe(
  tap(x => console.log('emit:')),
  take(3)
).subscribe((x)=>{
  data$.next(x)
});

const pipedData$ = data$.pipe(
  debounceTime(30),
  share(),
  map(x => Math.random()),
);

console.log("--=-=-=-=--=-=----=-=-=-=-==-")
pipedData$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
pipedData$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
pipedData$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to move `share` below `map` to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: thanks! on this example it fixes the issue - I tried first on my project where that doesn't help to decrease the number of calculations somehow.. will keep digging. any chance to get number of subscribers from the source?

Comment: if it keeps digging try to use exhaustMap that ignores parent stream until internal one has been done. About amount of subscribers. I don't have an answer, but I think the answer is somewhere in the source code of the share operator. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/share.ts

Comment: Actually it is: https://take.ms/Vakrh I've created my own pipe operator and was able to find amount of final subscribers.

Comment: even more easier: right in the `next.source._refCount` variable https://take.ms/hUsdG